# When retrieving data from the server in dispatch queue, how to handle application going to background?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I am creating an application where I am retrieving data from the server like below:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    [self retrievedatafromserver];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //UIUpdation, fetch the image/data from DB  and update into your UI
    });

});
```

How do I retrieve data from the server even if application goes to background?

Thanks & Regards
sumana

Answer (score 0):

When your app enters background mode. you can access code for couple of seconds. Suppose the background queue is still performing and you entered background. then you might need to recall the method when app entered foreground. (take a bool variable and check whether the process is completed or not, if process is completed no issues. if not call the method again.).

If you want to make app run in background mode also then you need to request for background run         mode in plist. See this link for reference only for these features we can active background run mode  and you can active any of them according to you usage http://blogs.innovationm.com/support-for-applications-running-in-background-ios/

Comment: for your reference http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-background-fetch/ ,http://www.devfright.com/ios-7-background-app-refresh-tutorial/  ,http://hayageek.com/ios-long-running-background-task/ ,http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/registering_applications_to_run_in_background/

Answer (score 0):

If Your scope of project is in only iOS 7 then you can use A new background mode which comes in the iOS 7 and onwards. You can fetch the data in background mode without any extra efforts of coding.

[image: Background fetch]

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
```

Now that your app already knows to initiate background fetch, let’s tell it what to do. The method `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` will assist in doing so. This method is called every time that a background fetch is performed, and should be included in the AppDelegate.m file. The complete version is provided below:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    id topViewController = navigationController.topViewController;
    if ([topViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]]) {
        [(ViewController*)topViewController insertNewObjectForFetchWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not the right class %@.", [topViewController class]);
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
    }
}
```

Now in your controller. Do like that

```
- (void)insertNewObjectForFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"Update the tableview.");
    self.numberOfnewPosts = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:4];
    NSLog(@"%d new fetched objects",self.numberOfnewPosts);
    for(int i = 0; i < self.numberOfnewPosts; i++){
        int addPost = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:(int)([self.possibleTableData count]-1)];
        [self insertObject:[self.possibleTableData objectAtIndex:addPost]];
    }
    /*
     At the end of the fetch, invoke the completion handler.
     */
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

**Note :-** If you have to give supportability on iOS 6 and below then avoid this approach. Because it's not available.